# I am doing docker Jupyter deep learning course and ran in to a problem with importing keras libraries and packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, libraries

[I tried running this command but i get erros that i dont have tenserflow 2.2 or higher. But I checked and I have the correct version of tenserflow. I also did pip3 install keras command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCqu6.png) 
I know for a fact that all of the code is correct because it worked for my teacher the other day and nothing has changed. I just need to run his commands but i keep running into problems

I am doing this course following everything he does in a recorded video so there must be no issue there but for some reason it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

just install tensorflow as requested in the last line of the error message: `pip install tensorflow`. It is needed as backend for Keras.

Also, since keras is part of tensorflow now, I recommend to write imports as `from tensorflow.keras.[submodule name] import`  instead of `from keras.[submodule name] import`